# VSCODE - Associate phtml to php on OSX

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the plugins folder I see various languages and within those folders I see ticino.plugin.json file where file extensions are associated with the given plugin. However, PHP is not in this folder, and none of the ticino.plugin.json files have the PHP extension associated with them.

I do see in the client/vs/languages folder that there is php folder, but there is nothing that I can find that would allow me to associate the additional file extension.

Comment: I just got the bright idea to grep the entire directory recursively and found it. For those that find this, the path to the file is:

/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/server/lib/mime.js

Underneath this line:

'.php': 'application/x-php',

Add:

'.phtml': 'application/x-php',

Restart VSCode and you're in business.

Comment: We have fixed this in the next update of VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

I did similar, I cloned the c# plugin and renamed it, then added my extensions. Take a look, https://github.com/genecyber/connectiq-build